# django get data response from specific ip

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am working on an API integration. I am using django==1.10.5 and python34. The app involves sending request from my server to another server which is connected through a VPN.

```
password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
spid = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
serviceid = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
sendershortcode = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
initiator = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
initiator_password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
recieveridentifier = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

body = """<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:req="http://api-v1.gen.mm.vodafone.com/mminterface/request">
<soapenv:Header>
 <tns:RequestSOAPHeader xmlns:tns="http://www.huawei.com/schema/osg/common/v2_1">
         <tns:spId>"""+spid+"""</tns:spId>
         <tns:serviceId>"""+serviceid+"""</tns:serviceId>
         <tns:spPassword>"""+encoded_password+"""</tns:spPassword>
         <tns:timeStamp>"""+reqTime+"""</tns:timeStamp>
      </tns:RequestSOAPHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<req:RequestMsg>
<![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request xmlns="http://api-v1.gen.mm.vodafone.com/mminterface/request">
<Transaction>
    <CommandID>SalaryPayment</CommandID>
    <LanguageCode></LanguageCode>
    <OriginatorConversationID>"""+originator+"""</OriginatorConversationID>
    <ConversationID></ConversationID>
    <Remark></Remark>
    <Parameters>
        <Parameter>
            <Key>Amount</Key>
            <Value>200</Value>
        </Parameter>

    </Parameters>
    <ReferenceData>
        <ReferenceItem>
            <Key>QueueTimeoutURL</Key> 
            <Value>http://138.197.41.74:80/user/test/</Value>
        </ReferenceItem>
    </ReferenceData>
    <Timestamp>"""+reqTime+"""</Timestamp>
</Transaction>
<Identity>
    <Caller>
        <CallerType>2</CallerType>
        <ThirdPartyID>broker_4</ThirdPartyID>
        <Password>k+JtvqNV3eg=</Password>
        <CheckSum>CheckSum0</CheckSum>
        <ResultURL>http://138.197.41.74:80/results/B2C/</ResultURL>
    </Caller>
    <Initiator>
        <IdentifierType>11</IdentifierType>
        <Identifier>"""+initiator+"""</Identifier>
        <SecurityCredential>YwBlXbjEFjh/UQ0cZhrk+4X9TxAIc3z8zf4rXZRZRLW32cm+c/lJYQ3ZFVThna+41x8EukAHZhuR44QiF5J1GF/9QaYwK1i1rIX2i/Fa9bRJ4fn/REYd/vE1/pUPn4GnfLib151RYQyO7KsLipLFk8Hr9SYq62MSrOxgyAd1bJXQ4SdEJwk0LtCZSTWBaZySbPJt/P0FBfG71kLkrP0P0pn1cuuuJoA3KJ5+RuX5WpsXR0HFFyyJFEwAlQ9oSmKW5fzCwEKMaKTKgScfyDXmhuiFZvrSmdV3H0o4Hhl17IQR8M1fwIk9JfxrSUqVRBrEqVKJrOOlSF/T7xLJTo0fpQ==</SecurityCredential>
        <ShortCode>777133</ShortCode>
    </Initiator>
    <PrimaryParty>
        <IdentifierType>4</IdentifierType>
        <Identifier>777133</Identifier>
        <ShortCode>777133</ShortCode>
    </PrimaryParty>
    <ReceiverParty>
        <IdentifierType>1</IdentifierType>
        <Identifier>"""+recieveridentifier+"""</Identifier>
        <ShortCode>ShortCode1</ShortCode>
    </ReceiverParty>
    <AccessDevice>
        <IdentifierType>1</IdentifierType>
        <Identifier>Identifier3</Identifier>
    </AccessDevice>
</Identity>
<KeyOwner>1</KeyOwner>
</request>]]></req:RequestMsg>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"""

headers = {'content-type': 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8'}
url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx:xxxx/mminterface/request"
response = requests.post(url=url, headers = headers, data = body)

#print (response.content)
respO = xmltodict.parse(response.content)
myresponse = json.dumps(respO)
```

This code works fine i am able to get a respose from the other server.
My question is the other server is sending some other data which am getting when i tcpdup response i.e. tcpdump -A -s 0 'src xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'

From doing this am getting this content.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <res:ResultMsg xmlns:res="http://api-v1.gen.mm.vodafone.com/mminterface/result">
            <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <Result xmlns="http://api-v1.gen.mm.vodafone.com/mminterface/result">
                    <ResultType>0</ResultType>
                    <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
                    <ResultDesc>The service request has been accepted successfully.</ResultDesc>
                    <OriginatorConversationID>Z8MPEFVZ</OriginatorConversationID>
                    <ConversationID>AG_20170508_00006c8d2d96c6efbeab</ConversationID>
                    <TransactionID>LE80192FMG</TransactionID>
                    <ResultParameters>
                        <ResultParameter>
                            <Key>TransactionReceipt</Key>
                            <Value>LE80192FMG</Value>
                        </ResultParameter>
                        <ResultParameter>
                            <Key>TransactionAmount</Key>
                            <Value>200</Value></ResultParameter>
                        <ResultParameter>
                            <Key>B2CWorkingAccountAvailableFunds</Key>
                            <Value>0.00</Value>
                        </ResultParameter>
                        <ResultParameter>
                            <Key>B2CUtilityAccountAvailableFunds</Key>
                            <Value>5508.00</Value>
                        </ResultParameter>
                        <ResultParameter>
                            <Key>TransactionCompletedDateTime</Key>
                            <Value>08.05.2017 09:37:07</Value>
                        </ResultParameter>
                        <ResultParameter>
                            <Key>ReceiverPartyPublicName</Key>
                            <Value>254703381233</Value>
                        </ResultParameter>
                        <ResultParameter>
                            <Key>B2CChargesPaidAccountAvailableFu 06:38:49.685570 IP 196-201-214-127.safaricom.co.ke.60575 > mambowallet.http: Flags [P.], seq 1380:1741, ack 1, win 4380, length 361 ..gP...5 ..nds</Key>
                            <Value>-275.00</Value>
                        </ResultParameter>
                        <ResultParameter>
                            <Key>B2CRecipientIsRegisteredCustomer</Key>
                            <Value>N</Value></ResultParameter>
                        </ResultParameters>
                        <ReferenceData><ReferenceItem>
                            <Key>QueueTimeoutURL</Key>
                            <Value>http://138.197.41.74:80/user/test/</Value>
                        </ReferenceItem>
                    </ReferenceData>
             </Result>]]>
     </res:ResultMsg>
 </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can someone help how i can get this content on the django view?
[tcpdump image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ6PO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can do a tcpdump inside your python code using subprocess:

```
from subprocess import check_output

out = check_output(['tcpdump','args'])
```

you get the response in out and then you can work with it. for example:

```
out = check_output(['tcpdump', 'ether[0] & 1 = 0 and ip[16] >= 224'])
```

and you need to be root also

Comment: From response = requests.post(url=url, headers = headers, data = body) I get the first I get the first XML response there after the peer IP sends another XML data which is the second XML data I have added above. This data is from doing tcpdump to see data sent to my IP port 80. My question is how can I get this second response to my code

Comment: How do you tcpdump from python code? Is this your question?

Comment: Yes or how do I get this data that I am getting from tcpdump to my python code.

Comment: From that am getting Command '['tcpdump', 'args']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. There is a TCP dump image attached above on the question. I would like to get the XML data on the image to a variable in my code.

Comment: That xml data  should be in variable 'out'. You can print  this variable to see how you can parse it.